# How can I disable all display managers?

Tags: boot, xserver, display-manager

When I boot my computer, I want to be greeted by a text terminal, like TTY. This way I want to be able to log in and type `startx` to start the GUI.

If I could get TTY to start on boot instead of a display manager, that would be enough.

Answer (score 13):

Assuming your distribution uses systemd, systemd's default target is `graphical.target`.

You can check the default with:

`systemctl get-default`

You can change the default to `multi-user.target` with:

`systemctl set-default multi-user.target`

Answer (score 8):

Run these steps:

### **Edit your grub**

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

**Change from:**

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

**Change to:**

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"
```

**Update Grub with**

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

**Disable the Lightdm manager:**

```
$ sudo systemctl disable lightdm.
```

Now when you reboot it'll stop at the text login prompt.

**Note:**

While the command **`startx`** will give you an **X** session, it will not give you the expecited environment you are familiar with.  To get a normal Ubuntu Desktop session you will have to start Lightdm.  You can do this with:

```
$ sudo systemctl start lightdm
```

Comment: When you say "not expected environment" - what do you mean? What does it look like and how is it different?